# How to avoid a circular dependency between a GUI and the rest of a program?

Tags: python, circular-dependency

I have two classes. One which is a GUI with the program, the other which actually controls all of the underlying actions that happen with the program.

```
class A(object): #GUI
    def __init__(self, inst):
        self.program = inst

    def foo(self):
        #Access B.a and B.b down here somewhere      

class B(object):
    a = []
    b = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.GUI = A(self)

    def bar(self):
        self.GUI.foo()
```

There's a pretty obvious circular dependency between these two classes, but I'm not 100% sure what a good way to fix it would be.

EDIT: The program needs input from the GUI to function properly

Comment: this is a broad question.  try searching for "circular dependency design pattern" and look thru some of the techniques that can be used.

Comment: There's a circular dependency only because you create one.  It's sometimes better to get the program to work *without* a GUI, then layer an event-driven GUI "on top" of it.  Your program's objects shouldn't need references to a GUI (imagine if you built the program without a GUI).

Comment: @jdigital Create an object, C,  that holds B.a and B.b, then have both A and B keep track of an instance of C?

Comment: @jedwards A problem I didn't previously mention is that the program needs input from the GUI to complete its function.

Comment: @Retronix Yes, but does it have to **know** that the input comes from the GUI? You should split your program: some functions receive the input (as a string/number/whatever) and do the work and return the result, then the GUI code **only** takes the input from the user, calls the functions from the other part of the program and displays the result.

Comment: Even if you have some form of "interactive" computation which requires user interaction you can always: 1) just split the computation in N steps and call the difference steps when needed or 2) write a coroutine and let the GUI send the input/get the output of the different steps. In both cases there is no need for the "functional code" to have a handle of the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a circular dependency. That would only happen if `foo` ever calls `self.inst.bar`.

Using the above snippet the following runs to completion:

```
b = B()
b.bar()
```

So if not 'recursive', then what is the meaning of 'circular' in this context?
There's not much of a problem with A having a reference to B and B also having a reference to A. But you do want to have a strategy for how they interact. Maybe read up a bit on MVC:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm